# How do I switch off my engine?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I have seen videos of players switching off their engines and floating in space, and their screens iceing up.

I can't seem to find this, I thought it was on the (4) right hand UI, but all I can see is silent running, am I missing something?

Answer (score 6):

It is in the right hand UI (4), but it's under *modules*, not *functions*. Use the panel tab change (Q/E), then up/down to the thrusters (W/S) and the UI select button (space?) to disable the engines/thrusters.

If you want to get the full cooling effect, you'll want to shut down more than just the engines. Probably leave only life support and power plant running... Start at the top of the list to shut down the highest power draw things.

Comment: Ok I see it's shutting down thrusters not engines

Comment: You could always turn Life Support off too - just not for too long. Can you even turn the power plant off? I tried once. Didn't work. (Xbox One)

Comment: @Iszi - Yes, you can always turn life support off, too, and how long you can do that for depends on the rating of your life support. No, I don't think you can turn off the powerplant.

Answer (score 2):

As Cmdr Freiheit has explained, use the Modules tab to shut thrusters down to float in space.

However, I don't think shutting down everything (except Power Plant as that cannot be shut down) produces the freezing effect any more, those videos you've seen are from Beta or earlier.

If you want to see the awesome freezing effect for yourself, you need the Heat Sink Launcher in later builds.

Comment: No, I've definitely hit the freezing effect in the Gamma, and maybe in the release, too. Took several minutes. Probably depends on your power plant's heat efficiency and overall ship heat efficiency. If you don't have a high-end life support, it probably takes longer than your emergency oxygen supply lasts. The heat sink will get you to freezing cold *much* faster, of course.

Comment: I've shut down pretty far and not gotten the freezing effect, but I wasn't deliberately trying for it. (So, I might have left thrusters on, or a couple other odds & ends.) However, in CQC, I have gotten that effect whenever I drop a Heat Sink from my Eagle. (Xbox One)

Comment: I've now deliberately tested for the freeze effect via heat reduction in the main game, (without using heat sinks yet, though) and still don't really feel like I achieved it. There was maybe a little fog on the cockpit, but nothing like what I've seen (and heard) when using a heat sink in CQC. I think I got my heat down to 7% or so. I'll have to do some more thorough comparison testing in something that has heat sinks sometime. Thinking two possibilities: 1. Only heat sinks can get you cold enough. / 2. Freeze effect indeed requires heat sink for "game design choice" reasons.

Comment: Or a third: 3. It's not *being* cold that makes you "freeze" - it's cooling down very quickly. And only heat sinks cool you down quick enough.